# Change Visibility with CheckBox - Android

Tags: android, checkbox, progress-bar, visibility

I want to change the visibility of the `ProgressBar` according to the checked `CheckBoxes` , but when I implement the following code, the `ProgressBar` goes invisible forever

```
ProgressBar progressBar1 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    ProgressBar progressBar2 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
    CheckBox checkBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    CheckBox checkBox2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);

    progressBar1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        progressBar2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    if (checkBox1.isChecked() && checkBox2.isChecked()) {
        progressBar2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else if (checkBox1.isChecked()) {
        progressBar1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you have to set the visibility code in the setOnClick listener of the checkbox

    checkBox1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(checkBox1.isChecked())
                {
                  progressBar1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             }
              else
            {
             progressBar1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
             }
                }

        });

       checkBox2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 if(checkBox1.isChecked() && checkBox2.isChecked()) {
                            progressBar2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        } else {
                            progressBar2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                }

        });
```

Comment: please edit your answer, it's not fitting in my code.